# Chrome console bug?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

This question is not of any doubt or problem. Apparently it seems that I have stumbled upon a bug maybe on chrome console,

I use this code:

```
console.log("Before: ", this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes);
let attribute = this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes.find(item => item.id === null || item.id === undefined)

if(attribute) {
   let length = this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes.length;
   this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes.splice(length-1, 1);
   console.log("After: ", this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes);
}
```

Okay so the attribute is an array and it's an array of length 2 initially.
Now  I'm splicing one item from the array and printing it's value before and after the splice.

In the chrome console in the snippet before the array it shows (2) indicating the length as 2 but in the array itself it shows the length as 1 and also only one item in the "Before console of the array"
while things are obviously as expected in the "After console"
I'm attaching an image for better understanding
[image]

I'm curious, does anyone have any idea about this? Does anyone face this before or  am I only the one noticing it?

Comment: you need to deep copy the object if you don't want it to be changed.

Comment: To get around this: `console.log("Before: ", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedScorecard.scorecard_attributes)));`

Comment: Welcome to the world of side effects.

Comment: Hover of the `[i]` in each line. It tells you that the value was evaluated at the time you expanded the row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When console.log runs, chrome synchronously logs out a summary of what's there. The array has 2 elements, so the summary logs a (2). Chrome keeps a reference to the array in case you decide later on you want to see more data, but it does not clone the entire array.

Later on, when you click to expand the array, it shows more details, but it shows it based on what it looks like when you expand it, not when the log statement originally occurred. Since it has only 1 element, that's what it displays.

Comment: I'd also add that the easy workaround to log objects as they are at the given moment is to use `console.log( JSON.stringify( obj ) )`